# Find the limit $\rm\ \lim_{x\to\ - \infty }\ -\frac{1}{2}\ln \left|x-1 \right|+\frac{1}{4}\ln \left|x^{2}+x+1 \right|$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am obliged to find this limit:

$\rm\displaystyle\ \lim_{x\to\ - \infty }\ -\frac{1}{2}\ln \left|x-1 \right|+\frac{1}{4}\ln \left|x^{2}+x+1 \right|$

I have no idea how to start doing this. I am getting indeterminate form. I will be glad for any tips.

Comment: It would be better if you, at least, tried the problem!

Comment: Hint: reverse the two ln terms and bring the exponents inside the ln terms. Then combine into one ln term. Now try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln \left|x-1 \right|+\frac{1}{4}\ln \left|x^{2}+x+1 \right|$$
$$=-\ln \left|x-1 \right|^{1/2} + \ln \left|x^{2}+x+1 \right|^{1/4}$$
$$=\ln \left| \frac{x^{2}+x+1}{(x-1)^2} \right|^{1/4}$$
What happens when $x\to\pm\infty?$ Can you see why the limit of the term inside the $\ln$ is $1$?

Comment: I see. I use L'Hôpital's rule twice and prove that $\rm\displaystyle\ \left| \frac{x^{2}+x+1}{(x-1)^2} \right| \rightarrow 1$ and then whole limit $\rightarrow 0$. My biggest concern was with bringing two logarithms into one. Why did you write : $\rm\displaystyle\ \ln \left| \frac{x^{2}+x+1}{(x-1)^2} \right|^{1/4}$ but not $\rm\displaystyle\ =\ln \left| \frac{{(x^{2}+x+1)}^{1/4}}{(x-1)^2} \right|$ ?

Comment: That was unnecessary question. I figured it out already :D Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

$-{1 \over 2} \log |1-x| + {1 \over 4} \log |x^2+x+1| = {1 \over 4} (  \log |x^2+x+1| -\log |x-1|^2 = {1 \over 4} \log | {x^2+x+1 \over x^2-2x +1 } |
 $.